# In Firebase, when the verifyPhoneNumber method returns a verificationID to the client, what does that ensure?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

`verifyPhoneNumber:UIDelegate:multiFactorSession:completion:`

[Firebase API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/PhoneAuthProvider?authuser=0#-verifyphonenumber:uidelegate:completion:)

Regarding the above Firebase `PhoneAuthProvider` method, `verifyPhoneNumber`, when a `verificationID` is returned to the client through this method, what does that ensure? Does it ensure that this phone number is capable of creating and signing into Firebase Auth accounts? Furthermore, does it ensure this regardless of whether the client actually received an SMS code or not?

In other words, in order to sign into a Firebase Auth account using phone credentials, both this `verificationID` and the code sent to the client via SMS must be used in tandem. However, if all we want to do is ensure that this phone number *is capable* of creating and signing into a Firebase Auth account, is the act of getting a `verificationID` from this method sufficient to make that determination, regardless of whether or not the client actually received an SMS code?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to break down my answer to your questions piece by piece.

> Regarding the above Firebase PhoneAuthProvider method,
> verifyPhoneNumber, when a verificationID is returned to the client
> through this method, what does that ensure?

when the `verifyPhoneNumber` method returns a `verificationId` to the client, it mainly ensures that a verification process has been initiated on the Firebase servers for that phone number specifically.

To the best of my knowledge the process is:`

1. the client calls the verifyPhoneNumber method with a specific phone number.
2. Firebase initiates the verification process, and sends an SMS verification code.
3. the verificationId is returned back to the client. This id is the unique identifier (or token) for this instance of the verification process.

> Does it ensure that this phone number is capable of creating and
> signing into Firebase Auth accounts?

No, the receipt of a `verificationId` alone does not ensure that a phone number is capable of creating and signing into Firebase Auth accounts.

> Furthermore, does it ensure this regardless of whether the client
> actually received an SMS code or not?

Again, no. The `verificationId` itself does not ensure that the client has received an SMS code. This Id is returned with the verification process has been *initiated* successfully, but it does not guarantee that the SMS code has been delivered to or received by the client.

The purpose of the verificationId is to identify the verification process for a given phone number. It does not independently validate the phone number or confirm anything.

> In other words, in order to sign into a Firebase Auth account using
> phone credentials, both this verificationID and the code sent to the
> client via SMS must be used in tandem

Correct.

> However, if all we want to do is ensure that this phone number is
> capable of creating and signing into a Firebase Auth account, is the
> act of getting a verificationID from this method sufficient to make
> that determination, regardless of whether or not the client actually
> received an SMS code?

No, the act of getting a `verificationId` from the `verifyPhoneNumber` method is not sufficient to make the determination that a phone number is *capable* of creating and signing into a Firebase Auth account.

Remember this if anything: the `verificationId` is a token that represents that a verification process has been *initiated*, but does not validate. The validation process comes in the second step, where the user receives said code, and inputs that code into the client application.